# Best way to share class from ASP.NET Core controller to Winforms client side

Tags: c#, winforms, asp.net-core

I have a controller for example:

```
using GaiaProjectSoftwareDevelopmentExercise.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace GaiaProjectSoftwareDevelopmentExercise.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class OperatorsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly NumbersOperationService numbersOperationService;
        private DataBaseManager dataBaseManager = new DataBaseManager();

        public OperatorsController()
        {
            this.numbersOperationService = new NumbersOperationService();
        }

        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public IActionResult GetListOfOperators()
        {
            try
            {
                return Ok(new List<string>() 
                {   "AddNumbers", 
                    "SubtractNumbers",
                    "MultiplyNumbers",
                    "DivideNumbers",
                    "ConcatenateStrings" });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public IActionResult AddNumbers(double first, double second)
        {
            try
            {
                double result = numbersOperationService.Add(first, second);
                dataBaseManager.addValues("AddNumbers", first.ToString(), second.ToString(), result.ToString());
                return Ok(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public IActionResult SubtractNumbers(double first, double second)
        {
            try
            {
                double result = numbersOperationService.Subtract(first, second);
                dataBaseManager.addValues("SubtractNumbers", first.ToString(), second.ToString(), result.ToString());
                return Ok(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public IActionResult MultiplyNumbers(double first, double second)
        {
            try
            {
                double result = numbersOperationService.Multiply(first, second);
                dataBaseManager.addValues("MultiplyNumbers", first.ToString(), second.ToString(), result.ToString());
                return Ok(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public IActionResult DivideNumbers(double first, double second)
        {
            try
            {
                double result = numbersOperationService.Divide(first, second);
                dataBaseManager.addValues("DivideNumbers", first.ToString(), second.ToString(), result.ToString());
                return Ok(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public IActionResult ConcatenateStrings(string first, string second)
        {
            try
            {
                string result = string.Concat(first, second);
                dataBaseManager.addValues("ConcatenateStrings", first.ToString(), second.ToString(), result.ToString());
                return Ok(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And I have a Winforms project like this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace GaiaProjectClientSide
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadOperations();
        }

        private const string apiUrl = "http://localhost:5207/Operators/";

        private async void LoadOperations()
        {
            // טען את ההיסטוריה מהשרת והצג אותה ב-RichTextBox
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync($"{apiUrl}GetListOfOperators");
                    comboBox1.DataSource = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show($"Error loading history: {ex.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    string _operator = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
                    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync($"{apiUrl}{_operator}?first={textBox1.Text}&second={textBox2.Text}").Result;
                    textBox3.Text = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show($"Error calculation: {ex.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is when I want to get complex object from my controller to my Winforms, and also I want to let to another developers to use my server-side controller so I have to let the world know the what is the object so then they will ask my server the action I will give them this complex object and they will know the right casting

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: If you haven't already done so, move your models into a class library that you could then reference from other projects. That way they could reference them and have something to map to. Might want to consider creating a client class that could use your WebAPI that you could consume in your app.

Comment: Does "complex object" include business logic?

Comment: _"also I want to let to another developers to use my server-side controller so I have to let the world know"_ some would call that an api. Usually you _at least_ document it - maybe using a static website. Some services may also provide client SDKs or its little brother: an abstractions library (maybe nuget).

Answer (score 1):

Asp.net core web api contains the swagger now. So there is no need to share a document or else to the client now.

The reason why I don't suggest you do this is, for your own application, you should share the class library to others, but for some other developer who want to use the api and he is not using the asp.net core to build the application, sharing the library is not a good idea.

By using the swagger, it will auto generate the example's result value format. Then the client could generate the model according to this json, like below:

[image: S]

And you could directly access this page by typing the `https://xxxxxxx/swagger/index.html`.